# Add and subtract values in query

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm trying to do the following, but with no success.

On Access, my query has, on column A two different values "Ins" and "Outs". And I want new column that sums 1 for each "Ins" and subtracts 1 from the sum each time that there's an "Outs"

Can anyone help me with this?

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: What does "no success" mean - error message, wrong result, nothing happens? That info should be in your question as well as the attempted SQL of query.

Comment: Then result will be cumulative sum or aggregated total sum?

Comment: Sorry for the lack of info on my behalf, wrote the question on my cellphone while riding the train. The answer you provided was exactly the query I attempted. Getting an aggregate total sum. But what I'm attempting to get, is a cumulative sum.

Answer (score 1):

Use IIf() expression in query.

For simple aggregate total:

```
SELECT Sum(IIf([A] = "Ins", 1, -1)) AS Tot FROM tablename;
```

If you want a running sum, use that expression in a correlated subquery and need a unique identifier field - autonumber should serve:

```
SELECT ID, (
    SELECT Sum(IIf([A] = "Ins", 1, -1)) AS RS FROM table AS Dupe 
    WHERE Dupe.ID<=table.ID) AS RunSum 
FROM Holidays;
```

This can also be accomplished on report using textbox RunningSum property.
ControlSource expression: `=IIf([A] = "Ins", 1, -1)`

Comment: Thanks @June7. That was exactly what I wrote on my query. The output is an aggregate total sum. But I am trying to get a cumulative sum. Any help on that?

Comment: Calculating a running sum is a common topic. See revised answer.